# Chartjs: customise legend based on background color

Tags: chart.js

I am creating a bar chart using charts. The current work is below:

[image]

The colour represents continents. Notice that the default legend is blue showing undefined. I want to have the legends showing each colour and its represented continent. That is, to be able to display legends of the bar's background and customise their label.

How can I achieve that?

Really appreciate your help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting all your data in a single dataset you will need to make a different dataset for each continent and then set the label of that dataset to the continent